# Google Sites API via CURL in PHP - Getting "Content is not allowed in prolog."

Tags: php, curl, google-sites

```
$curl = new Curl();
$data = 'Email='.urlencode('MYEMAIL@EMAIL.COM').'&Passwd='.urlencode('MYPASSWORD').'&accountType=GOOGLE&source=Google-cURL-Example&service=jotspot';
$curl->post('https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin',$data);

//match authorization token
preg_match("!Auth=(.*)!",$curl->response,$match);
$auth = $match[1];

//set curl headers
$curl->set_headers(array(
'Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8',
'Host: sites.google.com',
'GData-Version: 1.4',
'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth='. trim($auth)));

//get a list of sites associated with my domain
$curl->get('https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/clevertechie.mygbiz.com'); 

//contains data returned by $curl->get();
echo $curl->response;
```

So instead of getting the list of sites from $curl->response, I get a message - "Content is not allowed in prolog." I've looked everywhere and haven't been able to find a solution, please help! Thanks! :)

This is the XML that is supposed to be returned by the response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gAcl='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007' xmlns:sites='http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008' xmlns:gs='http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006' xmlns:dc='http://purl.org/dc/terms' xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:thr='http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0'>
<updated>2012-10-31T19:00:17.297Z</updated>
<app:edited xmlns:app='http://www.w3.org/2007/app'>2012-10-31T19:00:17.297Z</app:edited>
<title>My Site Title</title>
<summary>My Site Summary</summary>
<sites:siteName>my-site-title</sites:siteName>
<sites:theme>slate</sites:theme>
</entry>
```

I can't paste the source of "https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/clevertechie.mygbiz.com" because it can't be accessed directly without authorization token, which is specified in the headers. The only way to retrieve its data is by using the token in the headers which I've done. Instead of getting above XML, I'm getting "Content is not allowed in prolog".

var_dump of $curl:

```
object(Curl)#1 (11) { ["curl_resource":protected]=> resource(4) of type (Unknown) ["proxy":protected]=> bool(false) 
["proxy_type":protected]=> NULL ["response"]=> string(33) "Content is not allowed in prolog." ["time"]=> float(249)
 ["info"]=> array(26) { ["url"]=> string(59) "https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/clevertechie.mygbiz.com" 
 ["content_type"]=> string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8" ["http_code"]=> int(400) ["header_size"]=> int(676) 
 ["request_size"]=> int(1935) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(20) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) 
 ["total_time"]=> float(0.249) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.015) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.046) 
 ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.109) ["size_upload"]=> float(111) ["size_download"]=> float(33) 
 ["speed_download"]=> float(132) ["speed_upload"]=> float(445) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) 
 ["upload_content_length"]=> float(111) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.249) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) 
 ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_ip"]=> string(14) "74.125.224.194" ["primary_port"]=> int(443) 
 ["local_ip"]=> string(13) "192.168.1.133" ["local_port"]=> int(61985) ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" } 
 ["error"]=> NULL ["custom_headers"]=> NULL ["cookie_file"]=> string(46) "cookies.txt" 
 ["custom_curl_options":protected]=> array(3) { [47]=> int(1) [10015]=> string(111) 
 "Email=MYEMAIL&Passwd=MYPASSWORD&accountType=GOOGLE&source=Google-cURL-Example&service=jotspot" 
 [10023]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(49) "Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8" 
 [1]=> string(22) "Host: sites.google.com" [2]=> string(18) "GData-Version: 1.4" [3]=> string(320) 
 "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=DQAAAMMAAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" } } ["curl_options":protected]=> array(9) { [10018]=> string(74) 
 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1" [10016]=> string(22) 
 "http://www.google.com/" [13]=> int(60) [78]=> int(60) [19913]=> int(1) [52]=> int(1) [64]=> int(0) [81]=> int(0) [42]=> int(0) } }
```

$auth is just a string, its not supposed to be formatted as XML. I verified that there are no extra spaces or characters and it exactly matches the one returned by the first $curl->post request.

Comment: Can you dump your `$auth` variable before setting the headers (or `var_dump` the headers)? Also, could you paste in the *exact* source of `https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/clevertechie.mygbiz.com`? It may be that there is a problem with the XML (specifically space before the `<?xml?>` declaration)

Comment: On reading my own comment, I didn't mean to imply that you should share your `$auth` value... that would be a bad call :) However, I suspect that it's an issue with XML encoding, so do post the XML response that the file *should* return.

Comment: Could you also post a `var_dump` of `$curl`? Obfuscate any confidential data, but also make sure that string lengths are correct, as it's possible that `trim()` is missing a whitespace character... for instance, it doesn't catch zero-width-space characters (`\u200B`)

Comment: Check the contents of `$auth`, to make sure it's valid XML. Googling the error suggests looking for extraneous BOM character at the beginning.

Comment: Which line you are getting this error? I am sure none of the lines in the supplied code this error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Leave the request type as a POST (with the content being the atom xml payload), set the content type to “application/atom+xml” but pass all of the oAuth as a GET, i.e. as escaped (urlEncoded) values on the URL query string.